# Update webform status on load and update

Tags: webforms, i18n-l10n

I have a Drupal 6 website that uses webform-enabled node to allow users to signup to events. The site is multilingual and can only set submission limit per language. On page load and on webform submit, I want to count all submissions from all language and if the total is greater than a certain limit, I want to programmatically set the webform status to "closed".

**Which Drupal hook should I use here?** I tried hook_form_alter() but it only happens before the form is rendered, and will only display (or not display) the webform after a second reload. Also tried hook_nodeapi() where $op = 'load' but at this point the webform isn't attached to the node so I can't manipulate the data.

Please help.

Comment: `hook_init()` would probably make most sense for the "page load" event, `hook_form_alter()` is the right one for the webform submit. If you're asking which single hook you can use, there isn't one that straddles page initialisation and form submission, you'll need to implement 2 hooks

Comment: hook_init() does not provide me with the current node nid. dsm($node) is blank. I need a hook before page is built but after init. As for hook_form_alter(), how to add behavior and not completely override the submit? It seems each time I try something like $form['#submit'] = _my_custom_func it overrides the default behavior of form submit.

Comment: Just add to the array instead of overwriting (`$form['#submit'][] = '_my_custom_func';`) You can get the node with [`menu_get_object()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/6), wherever you are in the request